# Creating a chart on client and on the server using d3.js?

Tags: node.js, d3.js, babeljs

I'm developing a library which targets browser and server ( node.js ), when trying to create an SVG on the server i ran into the error "document is not defined", because for some reason d3.js depends on the document  object.

So i reached out for d3-node which depends on jsdom and probably will end up creating issues when building this library for the client.

One thing that is unknown to me is the fact I wish to generate same charts but when running on the browser i would like them to be interactive, which is something i can completely ignore when generating offline charts.

So i'm wondering if it's possible and worth to have a library that targets both environments and if possible have one simple build which runs on both environments?

Can't we use d3.js and generate the SVG string without depending on "document"? I believe the answer will be "NO" if i want to attach DOM events right? Therefore its likely i need to simply make a client build with all the features and design the library in a way it's possible to render the chart without adding DOM events.

Comment: were you able to find any library or use d3 for your purpose ?

Comment: unfortunately I ended up pausing that part of the project ( rendering SVG server-side ), i wish to get back into it soon.